# Can we create a Java app on BlueMix and schedule it to run daily?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We want to build a Java app, push it to BlueMix and schedule so that it runs once daily. At the moment Java Liberty on BlueMix offers either Web or Mobile app to be built. Is there anyway to build console application or an exe?

Answer (score 5):

I would package your application as a stand alone jar file and push it to Bluemix. You will need to use the no-route option to tell Bluemix that it is not a web application

```
cf push myjavaapp -p standalone.jar --no-route
```

Your application can contain the logic to run every day.

Or, you can convert your application to a web application - Add a simple servlet which will act as the entry point. Then, you can use a cron service to simply call this servlet url every time you want it to run.

Comment: I don't know where you'd schedule a cron job in Bluemix (where's the OS?), nor where an app would get a clock to run itself each day. The Workload Scheduler service is designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Bobby, if we are in the dedicated Bluemix world then what are the choices besides syndicating the workload scheduler service?

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule tasks via the Workload Scheduler service: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/WorkloadScheduler/index.html#gettingstarted

Example: http://heidloff.net/nh/home.nsf/article.xsp?id=18.12.2014081315NHEAGV.htm

Comment: Workload Scheduler service is the way to go.

Comment: @BobbyWoolf no it's not, it's too expensive it would cost 0.05$ per job,that's mean if you need to run something every 5 minutes, it would cost you 500$ per month.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody. I would like to add that we are using the WorkloadScheduler service with a customer and this works fine.

1- We first created an endpoint program that we deployed in Bluemix.
2- Then we add the WorkloadScheduler service to our space and left unbounded as explained.
3- Then launched the WorkloadScheduler interface, created a new ProcessLibrary, then a new "Task" and entered all General, Triggers, Steps infos.
4- The endpoint is set in the Triggers to run every night at 22:OO.
5- In the Steps we entered the endpoint as a RESTFul methode GET and as we do not expected any result we leave the others in default.

Tip: check in the Preferences if you are using the right time zone for you.

So far this works well for me. 
Is there any comment from the experts on how it could be improved? What about security for example and the use of UserId/Password to secure the call?

Comment: no you shouldn't use it , it's too expensive be careful , it would cost 0.05$ per job, if you run something evey one minute you will end up paying 800$ every month.